# Name of current value in Knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates, knockout.js

I'm getting started with Knockout.  I can't figure out how to setup up the binding in the valuesTemplate.  What is the name of the current value of the iterator?

```
<div id="knock">
    <p>Name: <input data-bind="value: Name" /></p>
    <table>
        <thead><tr><td>Value</td></tr></thead>
          <tbody data-bind="template: {name: 'valuesTemplate', foreach: Values}" />
    </table>

    <script type="text/html" id="valuesTemplate"> 
        <tr><td><input data-bind="value: value" /></td></tr> 
    </script>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = {"Name":"Fish","Values":["Cod","Salmon","Perch","Glish"],"Id":"lookups/1"};
    var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside of a jQuery Template, you can access the current context by using `$data` or `$item.data`, so like:

```
<script type="text/html" id="valuesTemplate"> 
     <tr><td><input data-bind="value: $data" /></td></tr> 
</script>
```

However, if you are using observables, you are going to want your values array to contain objects rather than just strings.

Comment: If you are using observables, then you will want your array of values to contain objects (even like { name: 'value' } ).  You can't make the values of individual items in an array observable.

Comment: I switched over to that.  Thanks for the tip.